# How can I access value of nested lists in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I want to access values of a nested list [ICMPDU,[0,1,2]] in robot framework.  I want to access the element 2 in the list in robot framework. Below is my code.Below code gives me output as 'Yes'[2]. Any suggestions?

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary
Library           Collections

*** Variables ***
@{ICMPDU_Val}     'Yes'    1    2
@{ICMPDU}         ICMPDU    @{ICMPDU_Val}

*** Test Cases ***
Network_web_page
  Log To Console    @{ICMPDU}[1][2]
```

Comment: That's why I say robotframework `language` sucks. Why they create that instead of just use Python? Why?

Answer (score 4):

The first problem is that you are *not* creating a list inside of a list.

Consider this line:

```
@{ICMPDU}         ICMPDU    @{ICMPDU_Val}
```

This will create a list composed of four values: `ICMPDU`, `Yes`, `1`, and `2`. That is because when `@` is used on the right hand side of a keyword, the list is expanded and each element becomes an argument to the keyword.

From the [robot framework users guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#list-variables) (emphasis added):

> When a variable is used as a scalar like ${EXAMPLE}, its value will be used as-is. If a variable value is a list or list-like, it is also possible to use as a list variable like @{EXAMPLE}. **In this case individual list items are passed in as arguments separately.**

If you want the list to be the second element of the list, you must use `$` instead of `@` when defining the variable:

```
@{ICMPDU}         ICMPDU    ${ICMPDU_Val}
```

The second problem is that the syntax for accessing array elements only works outside the braces if you have a single index. If you need somethime more complex, such as `[1][2]` you need to use [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax) and move the indexes inside of the curly braces.

For example, `${ICMPDU[1][2]}`

Answer (score 1):

Using the Collections Library:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Network_web_page
    ${li}=    Get From List    ${ICMPDU}    1
    ${res}=    Get From List    ${li}    2
```

Gives the output:

> ${li} = [u"'Yes'", u'1', u'2']
>
> ${res} = 2

and the variables as :

```
*** Variables ***
@{ICMPDU_Val}     'Yes'    1    2
@{ICMPDU}         ICMPDU    ${ICMPDU_Val}
```

Comment: Tried the above code but Get from list is just returning the first element in the list and not the entire list. Got the following output :  ${li}='Yes' and ${res}=e

Comment: @Say.W In the Variables section make sure that you are using `@{ICMPDU}         ICMPDU    ${ICMPDU_Val}` instead of `@{ICMPDU}         ICMPDU    @{ICMPDU_Val}`. Having the `$` while nesting the second list in the first makes all the difference